# How to increase the playback speed of a recorded WebEx meeting?

Tags: playback, video-playback, meetings, webex

My company records WebEx meetings.  Playing them back usually starts in IE and then jumps to a standard WebEx client (showing the shared screen and participants list), and also has the playback controls (play, stop, volume, slider), and a table of contents window (where you can navigate / jump between slides).

Is there any way to increase the playback speed of the meeting (like how Youtube now allows you to play .25, .50, Normal, 1.25, 1.50, and 2.0 times the speed)?  If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

If you convert the file to WMV, you can play it back at any speed in VLC Media player (free app)

1. Open the .arf file in Network Recording Player
2. Click File > Convert Format > WMV
3. Tick the Video checkbox (You may be able to skip this step?)
4. Click OK
5. Wait for the file to be converted
6. Open the converted file in VLC Media Player (free download - Google it)
7. In VLC: Play > Speed > Faster (press multiple times to go even faster)

Note: in VLC, you can open a Playback Speed tool window, if you click Play > Speed > --------------

Comment: That is exactly what I would do, except converting to WMV is disabled because the playback is streaming.  Is there any way to convert a streaming playback?

Comment: Not found a way. Looks like WebEx use a different guid for streaming vs download, so you can't just tweak the URL to get the download link.

Comment: its almost 2023 begining and still there is no way to convert .arf file to mp4/avi without webex url's :(

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved this by using [WebEx Recording Editor](https://support.webex.com/MyAccountWeb/knowledgeBase.do?root=Tools&parent=Knowledge&articleId=WBX20856) and dumping to a WMV video, then editing the WMV to perform timewarp/speedup in a non-linear editor (like Sony Vegas).

Answer (score 0):

In 2019: WebEx now lets one-click download the recording to a MP4 format.

On a windows PC, you can play the downloaded MP4 file using Windows Media player (version 12 or above).

Win Media player allows to change the playback speed by:
right click -> Enhancements -> Play speed settings

Reference: [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/media-player-12-how-can-i-change-play-speed-of/837f2fa3-d916-4808-b4e7-a0a216daf123)